# «Жаба-ага» или «жаба ага»?

Tags: раздельно-дефис

Писать с дефисом или раздельно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно Большой российской энциклопедии, *ага* — это [видовое название](https://bigenc.ru/biology/text/1850610). По общему правилу, дефис не ставится между двумя нарицательными существительными, из которых первое является понятием родовым, а второе — понятием видовым: *собака терьер, рыба акула.*
Но! К этому правилу есть уточнение: устоявшиеся научные названия пишутся через дефис — *мышь-полёвка, лук-порей*.
Так вот, в Пятиязычном словаре названий животных указано, что **жаба-ага [пишется через дефис](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJem8.png).**

Answer (score 0):

На этот вопрос точного ответа нет, но если отталкиваться от версии Википедии, то правильным написанием будет "**жаба-ага**". Хотя в Большой российской энциклопедии написано иначе, просто *ага.*